# How does multiple developers work with the same repository (Unity3D)?

Tags: plasticscm

I have been trying out Plastic SCM for a few weeks now.. and we still have issues in figuring out how to use Plastic SCM when multiple developers are working with the same repository.

We are currently working with Unity3D for our project, and for each time we try to merge our changes we always end up with some sort of problem.

We are currently using the Plastic SCM Cloud Edition.

What we have tried is to work directly against the Cloud Repo, but that ended up with problems merging (since the cloud edition isn't able to merge content "on the fly" in the cloud).

We then ended up creating local repositories that we then replicated the cloud repository to by simply pulling the repo, then made some changes and then tried to push the local repository. However.. we then received a new error telling us something about the MemoryStream...

So... how are we supposed to work with Plastic SCM Cloud Edition when in a small team of 2-5 developers when working with Unity3D?

Answer (score 0):

Your last approach make sense if you don't need an on-premise server in your office.

Plastic Cloud Edition is the sum of the Plastic SCM software plus a Plastic Cloud server and storage all packaged together in a single pay-as-you-go subscription.

The client software and local repositories are installed on each developer’s computer, and then he will push/pull to the cloud organization.

You commented that your workflow requires branching and merging, so the checkin, update, create branch and merge will be local operations and then you be just connecting to the cloud to push/pull your changes.

This "MemoryStream" message could be a "hard drive is full" issue, but we would need more details to confirm it. If you reach us, we will try to debug it we will also help you to configure your setup: support at codicesoftware dot com